# Making expander control header in to bold

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

I am going to create **n** number of *expander* control dynamically at runtime as follows,

```
theExpanderCaption[counter] = new TextBlock();
theExpanderCaption[counter].FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
theExpanderCaption[counter].Text = ITEMIMP.DataConstants.GroupIds.GetGroupCaption(group.GroupId);

theGroupExpander[counter] = new Expander();
theGroupExpander[counter].Header = theExpanderCaption[counter];
theGroupExpander[counter].Margin = new Thickness(10);
theGroupExpander[counter].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
theGroupExpander[counter].IsExpanded = true;
theGroupExpander[counter].Content = this.theGroupGrids[counter];
theGroupExpander[counter].Style = null;
```

In the above code I am using  array of *text block* to set expander header (to make it bold). Here the drawback is I have to use **n** no of *text block* controls. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Elaborate your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create FormattedText at runtime and set to Header. In the constructor of FormattedText you can define foreground brush.

Answer (score 6):

It'd help to see your markup, but I assume you have something like this:

```
<Expander Header="My Header">
    ...
</Expander>
```

You can specify the header like this, and set all the format options you'd like:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="My Header" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Expander.Header>
    ...
</Expander>
```

Comment: how can i achieve this at runtime, if i am creating expander control dynamically(setting header without using text block)

Comment: No trigger as such, By default the **_is expanded_** property is set to true

Comment: One more detail, that might help if only a part of the text should be formatted:
`<Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">
                    <Run FontWeight="Bold">BOLD TEXT</Run>
                    <Run FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="Red">NORMAL, BUT RED TEXT</Run>
                </TextBlock>
</Expander.Header>`

Answer (score 5):

Add below in your Window/Page resources. This will be applied to all the expanders within the window

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Width="{Binding
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                    Mode=FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},
                    Path=ActualWidth}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
```